# Tests that require orchestration of multiple containers in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci

I am considering porting a legacy pipeline that builds and tests Docker/OCI images into GitLab CI/CD. I already have a GitLab Runner in a Kubernetes cluster and it's registered to a GitLab instance. Testing a particular image requires running certain commands inside (for running unit tests, etc.). Presumably this could be modeled by a job `my_test` like so:

```
my_test:
  stage: test
  image: my_image_1
  script:
  - my_script.sh
```

However, these tests are not completely self-contained but also require the presence of a second container (a database, i.e.). At the outset, I can imagine one, perhaps suboptimal way for handling this (there would also have to be some logic for waiting until `my_image2` has started up and a way for `kubectl` to obtain sufficient credentials):

```
  before_script: kubectl deployment create my_deployment2 ...
  after_script: kubectl delete deployment my_deployment2 ...
```

I am fairly new to GitLab CI/CD so I am wondering: What is best practice for modeling a test like this one, i.e. situations where tests requires orchestration of multiple containers? (Does this fit into the scope of a GitLab job or should it better be delegated to other software that `my_test` could talk to?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first look should be at [Services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/).

With services you can start a container running `MySQL` or `Postgres` and run tests which will connect to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. This brought me a step forward and I have posted a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67729033/exec-into-service-in-the-context-of-gitlab-ci-cd-job).