# Exec into service in the context of GitLab CI/CD job

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci

I want to employ GitLab CI/CD for a test that involves two containers. The test requires that both containers are up and that a script is then run in one of them (with semantics akin to `kubectl exec ... script.sh` or `docker exec ... script.sh`). I've tried modeling this with [`services`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/) thanks to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67727728/9164810) received:

```
my_test:
  stage: test
  services:
  - my_image_2
  image: my_image_1
  script:
  - my_script.sh
```

However, the problem with this is that `my_script.sh` now in effect replaces the entrypoint of `my_image_1`. The container then behaves differently and this obviously makes the test fail. Is there a known pattern for overcoming this situation, something conceptually akin to `script: ["docker exec ... script.sh"]`?

I have considered running also `my_image_1` as service. But it is a web server, so there is e.g. no `sshd` running inside, hence no outside connectivity for executing the script either. I've also considered adding `/entrypoint.sh &` as first step in `script:`, but this seems like a hack and would also require an additional health check as 2nd step, because the web server's start in the background will be relatively slow, so `my_script.sh` (the then 3rd step) would have to be delayed. What is a good way forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now opted for an approach where I call `kubectl` multiple times in the job's `script`. This gives me greater control over the exact orchestration than GitLab CI/CD's `service` feature would allow (and as a welcome side effect, I can still start the tests with `kubectl exec`). `kubectl` obtains its permissions via a token that belongs to a dedicated `serviceaccount` in Kubernetes. That token is stored in Vault and the GitLab CI/CD job gets it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the [entrypoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#extended-docker-configuration-options) of the image specified with the `entrypoint` keyword and set it how you want it to behave.

```
my_test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - my_image_2
  image: 
    name: my_image_1
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - my_script.sh
```

Comment: Well, without an entrypoint (and without modifying `my_script.sh`) the server won't start up and the tests will fail.